# How to remove App ID from iTunes in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, app-id

I found that my app's bundleIdentifier is different from my App ID of iTunes. So I want to make new appID, but I can not make App ID having bundleIdentifier 'com.A.B' different from the one of App ID that I already have one :'com.A.C'. So I try to remove one I have but when I tried, it says

> An unspecified error occurred.
>
> The App ID 'ABC1D2FG3.com.A.C' appears to be in use by the App Store, so it can not be removed at this time.

So I removed all certificates and provisioning profile belonged to that AppID. But it still says same message.

I think the image is the problem. I set to upload my app, but I don't know how to cancel it.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove your app from the App Store first.
According to [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH31-SW37), you can only delete your app if it has **at least one approved version** and is currently in **one of the following statuses**:
[image]

Comment: thank you, hayot! But as i said i found no way to delete that app in that image above

Comment: I think i am in 'prepare for submission' but i failed to deleye

Comment: You can't delete it if it never been "Ready for sale" before.

Comment: you can't delete the app, but go to app details(More>About this app) and change the bundle!